# What does this old handwritten document say?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

[image]I have some documents written in German. I can barely make out some of the words. May be someone could read or understand what kind of document this is?
Thank you. I also upload some of them

Comment: No image in your post, please attach one.

Comment: @Аня: You haven't posted an image!

Comment: Thank you all! 
I'm not this used to this platform yet.
Now it's uploaded

Answer (score 2):

The document is a thank-you letter whose writer (A) thanks the recipient (B) for sending them one of their (B's) writings (*Schrift*).

Judging by your other documents, B might be Dr. Krahmer, theology adjunct at the Marburg university. In this case, the *Schrift* might have been an academic essay or the like.

> Kassel am 17. Oct. 1838
>
> Ew. Wohlgeboren
>
> danke ich ergebenst für die mit Schreiben vom 5. Oct. gütig mitgetheilte Schrift, die ein Beweis Ihres fortgesetzten Fleisses
> und Ihrer thätigen Wirksamkeit ist.
>
> Ich bin mit vorzüglicher Hochachtung
>
> Ew. Wohlgeboren

Translation

> Kassel, 17th October 1838
>
> I most respectfully thank you† for the writing you kindly sent me with your letter of Oct. 5th, which attests to your continual hard work and intense activity.
>
> Most respectfully,
>
> yours†
>
> [signature is missing]

†Here the writer uses the very formal, respectful address "Ew. [Euer] Wohlgeboren", which I chose not to translate for lack of an elegant English counterpart.

Comment: [Friedrich Gerstäcker's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Gerst%C3%A4cker) comment to "Euer Wohlgeboren": https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Wohlgeboren_und_Hochwohlgeboren

Comment: @PaulFrost A refreshing perspective!